# Maximizing $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}$ subject to $| \mathbf{x} | \preceq \mathbf{1}$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to find a maximum of quadratic function bounded above/below. The problem is formulated as

\begin{align}
&\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\max}~\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \label{eq:16a} \\
&\text{s.t.}\, \left. \begin{array}{l}
|\mathbf{x}| \preceq \mathbf{1}
\end{array} \right. \label{eq:16b}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is positive semi-definite.

The Lagrangian of this function is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} =  \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} + {\lambda}_-^T (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{1})-\lambda_+^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{1}),
\end{equation}
where ${\lambda}_-^T$ and ${\lambda}_+^T$ are Lagrangian multipliers. I am struggling with how to find the optimal $\mathbf{x}^*$ maximizing the objective. Thank you!

Comment: your usage of $\preceq$ is confusing. Is $\mathbf x$ a matrix, a vector, or a scalar?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for asking. $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, and $\preceq$ means a component-wise inequality.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Another approach, with which we might be able to find a solution in existing literature. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mathbf A$ here is symmetric (in addition to being positive semidefinite). With that, $\mathbf A$ has positive semidefinite and symmetric square root $\mathbf B := \mathbf A^{1/2}$. With that, we can rewrite your problem in the form
$$
\max_{\mathbf x} \|\mathbf B \mathbf x \|_2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \|\mathbf x\|_{\infty} \leq 1.
$$
In other words, we want the induced $p,q$ norm $\|\mathbf B\|_{\infty,2}$.

Comment: A small step forward: we have
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \mathbf x} = 2(\mathbf A \mathbf x)^T + \lambda_+^T + \lambda_-^T = 0 \implies \mathbf A \mathbf x = \frac 12 (\lambda_+ + \lambda_-),
$$
but I'm not sure where one would go from there

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit solution? Why do you think such a solution exists?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much for your comment. The induced norm approach looks interesting, and I am thinking how to proceed with this. BTW, I am still a bit confused since the form that you suggested also has the form of maximizing the convex set, subject to the convex set, which is the same to the original problem. What do I get between these two forms?

Comment: @SeanCho The key difference is "existing literature". I suspect that there are papers about computing induced $p,q$ norms

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much for your help. After studying for a few days, I could manage to solve this problem by using the norm approach. For others information, I used "InducedMatrixNorm" MATLAB program, which you can download from http://www.qetlab.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximization of a convex quadratic over the hypercube is a classical intractable problem, and you will not be able to device an algorithm which, in the worst case, performs much better than simply checking all the vertices of the hypercube.